# Generating Random Numbers Under some constraints

Tags: python, random

I happen to have a list y = [y1, y2, ... yn]. I need to generate random numbers ai such that 0<=ai<=c (for some constant c) and sum of all ai*yi = 0. Can anyone help me out on how to code this in python? Even pseudocode/logic works, I am having a conceptual problem here. While the first constraint is easy to satisfy, I cannot get anything for the second constraint.

EDIT: Take all yi = +1 or -1, if that helps, but a general solution to this would be interesting.

Comment: They aren't exactly *random* numbers if the sum of ai*yi=0 (that means they have a dependence on one another). What do you mean when you say you need them to be "random"? Can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean, possible give some code?  You want the value to fall between 0 and c (what value should it take or should it be user defined)? Also the `ai*yi = 0` part I do not understand that at all what is it?

Comment: Forgetting, for the moment, that the random numbers cannot be independent, how should they be distributed? I imagine that you mean uniformly distributed?

Comment: @Simon I mean something like ((a1*y1) + (a2*y2) +... +(an*yn)) = 0. Jeremy It is actually a constrained optimization problem, in which I need to find the maxima/minima of a function with solutions within constraints. The algorithm randomly generates solutions and updates them to eventually arrive at the optimum solution. This works for, say, if the function only had the 1st constraint of lying between 0 and c.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Dependence doesn't make the numbers non-random: it just makes them dependent.

Comment: @BillBell uniformly distributed, yes. I was wondering if I could do something like generate random numbers, check sum, and subtract values if it exceeds/add values if it is less. I don't really know how I should go about this.

Comment: c is real-valued?

Comment: C is a positive integer, all the 'ai's are positive floats. Also if it helps all yi are either 1 or -1, it can be merely reduced to generating random numbers ai such that a1 + a2 - a3 + a4 - a5 ... +an = 0, because I have a list of yi predefined.

Comment: I began to wonder if you needed an *additional* constraint, some kind of symmetry amongst the pseudorandom deviates? Otherwise, you choose a `n-1` U(0,c) deviates then the last value is just some linear function of the others.

Comment: That is what I will go with, I suppose, if I don't get a better answer. Generate some ai between 0 and c, and depending on their values, find an such that the sum of products is 0. However, won't that lead to unnecessary computation and rejection of values, for all the times, say sum of (ai*yi) upto n-1 is positive, and therefore n will need to be less than 0?

Comment: It seems you have one answer that might work.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the yi? For example, are their values bounded?

Comment: See above in the comments, all yi are either 1 or -1

Comment: If all y_i are +/-1, you should edit your question rather than state that only in the comments.

Comment: One more thought before I retire: The joint density of the random variables is 1. Can you somehow 'integrate out' the constraint to get an expression for the density of the constrained set of random variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a greedy (kind-of) correction algorithm. Basically, first you generate random `a` from a uniform distribution. That will give you some error (the sum won't be zero). You iteratively reduce that error by halving the `c[i]` for the term that gives you the largest contribution with the same sign as the error, until you can reduce that term by less than half in a way that gives you zero sum. Of course, the resulting `a` will not be uniformly distributed, but they will be close.

The reason I've done it with halving is in case having many values of `a[i]=0` is undesirable for your use case. You don't *need* to use halving, you could use another coefficient. In the implementation below, you can vary `reduce_coefficient` to change this. A value of `reduce_coefficient = 1.` will set `a[i] = 0.` until it can remove the sum (a proper greedy algorithm), while as `reduce_coefficient` approaches 0, you'll get an algorithm that will take a very long time to run and clips the largest terms in `a * y` to be some bound such that the sum is satisfied.

This should work for general `y[i]`, including your case where `y[i] = +/- 1`.

Here's an implementation:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randn(1000)
c = 2.
reduce_coefficient = 0.5
a = np.random.uniform(0, c, 1000)

sum = np.sum(a*y)
while sum != 0:
    a_y = a * y
    i = np.argmax(np.sign(sum) * a_y)
    if abs(sum) < abs(a_y[i] * reduce_coefficient):
        a_y_i_desired = a_y[i] - sum
        a[i] = a_y_i_desired / y[i]
        a_y[i] = a[i] * y[i]
        sum = 0
    else:
        sum -= a_y[i] * reduce_coefficient
        a[i] *= (1. - reduce_coefficient)
```

This will have some slightly-strange effect on the distribution of `a`, where values slightly less than to `reduce_coefficient * c` are more likely than other values, values close to `c` are less likely, and the distribution is otherwise uniform. If that's a problem, you can randomly set `reduce_coefficient` at each iteration. The only effect of this approach on the distribution will be to make values of `a` very close to `c` less likely.

```
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randn(1000)
c = 2.
a = np.random.uniform(0, c, 1000)

sum = np.sum(a*y)
while sum != 0:
    reduce_coefficient = np.random.uniform(0, 1.)
    a_y = a * y
    i = np.argmax(np.sign(sum) * a_y)
    if abs(sum) < abs(a_y[i] * reduce_coefficient):
        a_y_i_desired = a_y[i] - sum
        a[i] = a_y_i_desired / y[i]
        a_y[i] = a[i] * y[i]
        sum = 0
    else:
        sum -= a_y[i] * reduce_coefficient
        a[i] *= (1. - reduce_coefficient)
```

If you also care about the effect on the probability distribution for values close to `c`, you can set `i = np.random.randint(0, a.shape[0])` at each iteration instead of using `argmax`. The tradeoff is that more values will need to be modified. In practice, all of these modify very few values, which you can see if you plot the histogram of `a` before and after corrections.

Comment: Don't you mean `a[i] *= reduce_coefficient`in both the cases? Because `Newsum = k + x*ai*yi`, `Oldsum = k + ai*yi`, `Oldsum - Newsum = (1-x)*ai*yi`, Therefore `Newsum = Oldsum - (1-x)*ai*yi`, where `x = reduce_coefficient`

Comment: I've chosen the convention that reduce_coefficient is the maximum fraction by which you're willing to reduce `a[i]`. That means you check `abs(sum) < abs(a_y[i] * reduce_coefficient)`, because `abs(a_y[i] * reduce_coefficient)` is the maximum magnitude by which you're willing to reduce the sum. You can change the convention if you like, as long as you change how it is used everywhere.

Comment: You can think about the extreme cases where `reduce_coefficient` is 0 or 1, and how each line behaves in that case.

Comment: Okay so update, I think you either should change it to `sum -= a_y[i] * (reduce_coefficient)`. This will be because `new a[i] = old a[i] - coefficient*old a[i]`, and `new sum = old sum - yi*(old ai) + yi*(new a[i]) = old sum - y[i](old a[i] - new a[i]) = old sum - y[i]*(old a[i]*coefficient)`.

Comment: I see, you're right. And the line `a[i] *= 1. - reduce_coefficient` stays the same. If the amount we're reducing by is `reduce_coefficient`, then of course we should subtract (or reduce) `a_y[i] * reduce_coefficient` from `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `y(n)` not equal to zero. If you generate numbers

```
a(1),..., a(n-1)
```

You can determine the last one as

```
a(n) = - ( y(1)*a(1) + ... + y(n-1)*a(n-1) ) / y(n)
```

If `a(n)` is not less then `c`, repeat the procedure. Look: it can be you don't find a solution in a finite time :)
But I guess yes, if n is not so large.

If your problem is technical and not theoretical, you can try it and see if it works.

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in the comment on my question, plus it would lead to a load of unnecessary computation and rejections. I am thinking of trying to change the function I am trying to optimize so that I am left with only the 1st constraint. Thanks for the help, I don't know if it will work, n is >1000.

Answer (score 1):

This still leads to a very unsymmetric solution.

I set up a specific problem first.

```
>>> from random import uniform
>>> C = 9
>>> y = list(range(23,45))
```

I create one more random number than I need. Just my sloppy coding.

```
>>> ai_s = [uniform(0,C) for _ in range(len(y))]
```

Calculate your sum for just the first n-1 pairs, then calculate an 'ai' that would make the contribution of the final pair cause the full sum to be zero.

```
>>> partial_sum = sum([ai_s[i]*y[i] for i in range(-1+len(y))])
>>> remaining_ai = -partial_sum / y[-1]
>>> ai_s[-1] = remaining_ai
>>> full_sum = sum([ai_s[i]*y[i] for i in range(len(y))])
```

Verify apparent success of this enterprise.

```
>>> full_sum
0.0
>>> remaining_ai
-55.61967982871243
```

Now scale all of the ai's such that the largest one is no larger that 'C'.

```
>>> scale = remaining_ai / C
>>> ai_s = [ai/scale for ai in ai_s]
>>> full_sum = sum([ai_s[i]*y[i] for i in range(len(y))])
>>> full_sum
-1.1368683772161603e-13
```

Display the appalling results.

```
>>> ai_s
[-0.6762926525200684, -1.0583640594370294, -0.5122417560322818, -0.6809333760704214, -0.20217581044287009, -0.2156635979549709, -0.13351148980420294, -0.5498721696679322, -0.8367502192020138, -0.6485761671051807, -0.3756426962557057, -0.6732767276510332, -1.3123482119760639, -0.6525099994998692, -1.1226532211454199, -0.6194721784294968, -0.2262874341537195, -0.34684998461675415, -0.21587028201158823, -0.26403652293422325, -0.7801743698236504, 9.0]
```

One could adjust these values such that the final value was closer to the others in some sense. However, I sense that this approach samples an unappealing part of the space of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you need random integer values between 0 and c use `random.randint(0, c)`. For random floating point values between 0 anc c use `random.uniform(0, c)`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I was asking for help on the second constraint. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: a sorry, didn't read the second constraint properly... will think about it

Comment: are ai integer or float?

Answer (score 0):

I like splitting this problem up. Note that there must be some positive and some negative values of y (otherwise sum(ai*yi) can't equal zero).

1. Generate random positive coefficients ai for the negative values of y, and construct the sum of ai*yi over only the negative values of y (let's say this sum is -R).
2. Assuming there are "m" remaining positive values, choose random numbers for the first m-1 of the ai coefficients for positive yi values, according to ai = uniform(R/(m*max(y)).
3. Use your constraint to determine am = (R-sum(ai*yi | yi> 0))/ym. Notice that, by construction, all ai are positive and the sum of ai*yi = 0.
4. Also note that multiplying all ai by the same amount k will also satisfy the constraint. Therefore, find the largest ai (let's call it amax), and if amax is greater than c, multiply all values of ai by c/(amax + epsilon), where epsilon is any number greater than zero.

Did I miss anything?